# Add delimited text layer in QGIS3.22.10 LTR

Tags: qgis, text

I have commma delimited data exported from Excel to add to a map.  QGIS 3.22.4 LTR perfectly loaded layers selected using Data Source Manager > Delimited Text.

Now with exactly the same CRS in Settings, data cannot be added and there is the error message "The CRS must be selected". I cannot seem to find anywhere else to select the CRS.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

Expand `Geometry Definition`, fill in the fields that store x-/y-coordinates. Below, you see `Geometry CRS` where you can select the CRS your coordinates are saved in:

[image]